# Angular 2 - *ngSwitch not working

Tags: angular

When I set the `*ngSwitchCase` to `item.category` as seen below it will work and show the image.

The `{{item.category}}` will show left-hand-item in text on the screen.

However if I use:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'left-hand-item'">
```

then it does not work and I see nothing.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow">
        <div [ngSwitch]="item.category">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="item.category">
                {{item.category}}
                <img id="left-hand-item" class="layer img-responsive" name="left-hand-item" src={{item.fullItemURL}} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A plunker to reproduce would be helpful.

Comment: are you sure there is no blank space in front or behind the category name of `item.category`. Or underscore instead of dash, or any uppercase characters, or a typo... because that's the only reason i could see this go wrong